# How to prevent Chrome flickering when making navigation fixed on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am attempting to make a navigation menu become fixed on scroll.

This effect is perhaps best illustrated in in a fiddle as the fiddle describes it a lot more concisely than in prose:

```js
$(function() {

  var secondaryNav = $(".secondary-navigation");
  var secondaryNavScrollTop = secondaryNav.offset().top;

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > secondaryNavScrollTop) {
      $("body").css("padding-top", "100px");
      secondaryNav.addClass("stuck");
    } else {
      $("body").css("padding-top", "0px");
      secondaryNav.removeClass("stuck");
    }

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.section-jumbo {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 150px;
}
.secondary-navigation {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: tomato;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inherit;
  padding: 60px 40px 0 40px;
}
main section {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-jumbo">
</section>
<div class="secondary-navigation">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Intro</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Pictures</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Buy</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<main>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Portland artisan letterpress drinking vinegar salvia pork belly. Next level art party bitters 90's. High Life Pitchfork mixtape, hoodie photo booth hashtag viral retro asymmetrical bitters scenester Cosby sweater iPhone normcore slow-carb. Umami post-ironic
      Godard fap you probably haven't heard of them, seitan next level four loko. Locavore jean shorts church-key beard small batch. Drinking vinegar dreamcatcher pop-up banjo plaid narwhal, hoodie McSweeney's. Chambray blog Truffaut Blue Bottle tilde,
      squid asymmetrical High Life church-key keytar readymade.</p>
  </section>
</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem with this implementation is that in Chrome, the navigation menu *occasionally* flickers when having the `.stuck` class applied.

I suspect what I am observing is *lag* when the `padding-top` is applied to the `body` which happens at the same time the `.stuck` class is applied.

How can I avoid this bothersome flicker in Chrome?

*(Note that the flicker is not observable in the runnable code snippet for some reason. To reproduce you must run the code locally.)*

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it locally, and can't see the flicker in Chrome v.37.

Instead of doing both a $("body").css change and a SecondaryNav.addClass / .removeClass, try doing it as a single indivisible operation.

Simply do $("body").addClass("stuck") / .removeClass.

Then change your css to replace

```
.stuck { ...
```

with

```
body.stuck .secondary-navigation { ...
```